# Why are there fewer preimages of a critical values?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I am thinking about critical values of polynomials. In the quadratic case for $z^2-1$ the critical value $-1$ has only one preimage. I think this extends to all critical values of rational functions but I can't prove this. Is this true? How does one prove this in the case of polynomials of degree $n$. This seems like sa very basic question but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, a critical value  $v$ of say a polynomial $P$ is precisely a value of $v$ such that the polynomial $P(z)-v$ has a multiple root (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_(mathematics)).

If $P$ has degree $d$, then for any $y \in \mathbb C$, the polynomial $P(z)-y$ has exactly $d$ roots *counted with multiplicity*. But if $y$ is a critical value, then at least one root has non-trivial multiplicity, and so the number of roots (counted *without multiplicity*) must be less than $d$.

I'll leave to you how to adapt to the case of a rational map.

Comment: A little issue: "non-zero multiplicity".

Comment: ok, I changed "non-zero" into "non-trivial".